# Maximizing linear function (not necessarily continuous) over a compact, closed and convex domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control

I am interested in studying the following problem:
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)
\end{align}
where $\mu$ is a probability measure.  Assume that $\mathcal{D}$ is closed, covex and compact (in weak^{*} topology).

We know that if $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded then $\mu  \to \sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)$ is a continous functional and 
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)&=\max_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x), \text{ this steps is due to contintinuity,}\\
&=\max_{\mu \in \text{Extrem Points of} \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x), \text{ this step is due to linearity of the functional,}\\
\end{align}

**My question:** Now, assumes that $f(x)$ is continuous and positive but not bounded from above.  So, we can not claim that  $\mu  \to \sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)$ is a continous functional.

However, can we still say that

\begin{align}
\sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)=\sup_{\mu \in \text{Extrem Points of} \mathcal{D} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x),
\end{align}

from the linearity?

The example I have in mind is $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. 
Call ${\mathcal E}$ the set of extreme points of ${\mathcal D}$.
It is a consequence of [Choquet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory) that for every $\mu\in{\mathcal D}$ there exists a probability measure $\nu=\nu_\mu$ on ${\mathcal E}$ such that $\mu=\int_{\mathcal E}\rho d\nu(\rho)$ and in particular
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathcal E}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\rho(x)\right)d\nu(\rho)\leq\sup_{\rho\in{\mathcal E}}\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\rho(x)$$

Comment: The Choquet's theorem states if $D$ is compact and convex and if $f$ is an affine function on $D$, then there exists a probability measure $\nu$ supported on $\mathcal{E}$ such that  $f(c)=\int_{\mathcal{E}} f(e) d\rho(e)$.  I have a question. How are you getting $\mu = \int_{\mathcal{E}} e d\nu(e)$.   I don't think $\mu$ is an affince function. Can you explain this point a bit.

Comment: I was thinking of the version of Choquet's theorem which says that every
point of a compact convex set ${\mathcal D}$  is the
barycenter of a probability measure on the extreme points of ${\mathcal D}$, although I realize now that is not exactly the version on wikipedia.
But the version on wikipedia is good enough to answer your question: Let $F:{\mathcal D}\to{\mathbb R}$ be the affine function $F:\mu\mapsto\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\mu(x)$. Then we have $F(\mu)=\int_{\mathcal E}F(\rho)d\nu(\rho)\leq\sup_{\rho\in{\mathcal E}}F(\rho)$.